# onClick does not fire in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

Function does not fire on click event, on the certain div and everything what is inside

It is a functional component, my goal is to put onClick eventListener on reactFBLike component, I tried putting a ref on it, and then assigning eventList. also tried to wrap that in a ,  and  with target _self, and add EventListeners to them - no result.

```
    <SocialWidget title={t('social/title')}>
      <div className="socialWidget-icons">
        <a
          aria-label="Facebook"
          className="socialWidget-iconLink link--unstyled"
          href={url.facebook}
        >
          <Icon
            className="icon icon--base socialWidget-icon"
            kind="icon-facebook"
          />
        </a>
        <a
          aria-label="Instagram"
          className="socialWidget-iconLink link--unstyled"
          href={url.instagram}
        >
          <Icon
            className="icon icon--base socialWidget-icon"
            kind="icon-instagram"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <a
        onClick={() => console.log(work)}
        onKeyDown={doSmth}
        traget="_self"
      >
        <ReactFBLike
          href={url.facebook}
          language={language}
          share={false}
          showFaces={false}
          width="288"
        />
      </a>
    </SocialWidget>
```

Expected onClick to work, actual - no output.

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [react-fb-like](https://github.com/ZeroCho/react-fb-like/blob/master/src/ReactFBLike.jsx) source code executes some arbitrary script from facebook.net, which in turn executes another [script](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=f326691d4d7ba44dfa456988c31524c9) - the minified code is very hard to reason about, but Facebook's [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) does not show any way for custom event handlers.

So if the parent element's `onClick` event never fires, that means the element inserted by Facebook's script [stops event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). No idea if it might be against their policy to add any custom behaviour, I only found "[Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins)."

I do not believe there is an easy way how to solve your problem :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some consideration about that piece of code:

- There is a typo in traget (that should be target).
- Wrapping the ReactFBLike component with an `a` element is not a good idea to permform onClick event. A `span` element is a better choice.

To perform a simple text link log event this is the snippet

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Something...');
}

return (
  <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
    click Here
  </a>
);
```

or if you don't want to prevent default behaviour

```jsx
return (
  <a href="#" onClick={e => console.log('Something...')}>
    click Here
  </a>
);
```

in your case try this

```jsx
return (
  <span onClick={e => console.log('Something...')}>
    <YourComponent />
  </span>
);
```